# Two API's both using JWT authentication. How to authenticate between the two?

Tags: jwt, falconframework

I have two rest API's using a Bearer  auth header to a authenticate.

This works perfectly for the front-end of both systems, they call the auth endpoint, obtain a token and attach it for the duration of the session.

I need to be able to communicate between the two APIs, however, there's the problem that the JWT token expires after a set period of time, so I can't just store that token and attach it as a header.

What's the best way to manage authorization between the two systems?

Comment: The APIs themselves could have credentials, call the auth provider, obtain a token and use it when calling the other API. However, I think that in the current form your question is off-topic at SO because it would take an entire tutorial to answer it.

Comment: @tmt, yeah I thought about that myself, but then you've got to store the username+password combo in the system too. Which isn't ideal.

Comment: Well since both your REST APIs are on servers then you can add any token of your choice because it won't be available on the clients anyway which can protect your auth keys and you can verify the calls on either of the servers with the same key. Unless you have a different architecture.

Comment: @AyyubKolsawala, I'm using JWT with an expiration, so after a while the token stops working. There's no easy way for me to store the token as it'll stop working after a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually came up with a solution. I create an account for each system on it's counterpart. I then store these login details in a settings.local.json file, along with the API url for the other system.

When one system wants to communicate with the other, we first call the authenticate endpoint with the authentication details we have in the settings file, store the token returned and then call the endpoint we desire to call.

Essentially, exactly as you would as if it were the front-end.

Comment: One of the accounts could be an impersonation account. This is different from an admin-type account in the way that you know it's impersonating another user, which is usually contained in the metadata.